# Java generics extends syntax

Tags: java, generics

Can someone please explain me this class definition statement

```
public class BinarTree<Type extends Comparable<Type>> {...
```

I completely understand the purpose of it but not the syntax. According to me it should be just

```
public class BinarTree<Type extends Comparable> {...
```

What's the meaning of

```
<Type extends Comparable<Type>> ?
                         ^^^^
```

Comment: comparable is also a generic class(interface), and you want to use it in the generic way not in the raw way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is a generic interface. The reason behind that is to avoid casting to a specific type in the [`Comparable#compareTo(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method.

So if a `Type extends Comparable<Type>` this would mean that the `Type` will derive a method with signature

`public int compareTo(Type t1)`

instead of

`public int compareTo(Object o1)`

Answer (score 1):

The interface `Comparable` is itself a template.
So what you have there is a template with a parameter that must extend a template.
And specifically it must extend a template that received the **extending** class as a parameter.

Comparable is a template for interfaces that implement an order relationship and implement the method `int compareTo(TYPE o)`.
So it's normal to define a class:

```
  class FooBar implements Comparable<FooBar> {...
```

A binary tree wouldn't work for a class that was declared:

```
  class FooBar implements Comparable<Snafu> {...
```

That's because you would be able to compare `FooBar`s to `Snafu`s but not each other.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
public class BinarTree<Type extends Comparable>{...
```

`Type` can be any `Comparable`, also `Comparable<Integer>` or `Comparable<OtherType>`. If this is what you want, it is fine. Most times, I think you know what you want to compare exactly, so specialize the `Comparable` to `Comparable<Type>`

Comment: I would at least use `Comparable<?>` and not the raw type `Comparable` if that is what I wanted. Avoid using raw types - they only exist for backward compatibility with old Java versions.